# REST API Layer Orchestration using Spring Integration

Tags: spring, rest, spring-integration

We have around 6 individual REST services which we would be calling in our orchestration layer. for example "Calling service-1 to check if a bank account is of certain type, if yes, then call service-2, else call service-3".

Is Spring Integration messaging framework is a right tool for orchestrating calls to those services or its an overkill? Please suggest if there is a better way to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't suggest you better tool, because Spring Integration was the best one for me in the past and now it is my full time job. So, try to find other answers somewhere else.

Now about the point of `orchestration` with the Spring Integration. To be honest it's just a word which tries to describe the business logic in one application when it calls other external application according some conditions.

So, from big height having HTTP adapters in the Spring Integration, Transformers, Splitters, Routers and Gateways between them, we can say with confidence that messaging layer on Spring Integration fits your requirements and really can help you to distinguish business logic from the orchestration logic.

Not sure what to say else, but I can recommend take a look to the Spring Integration [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/) and pay attention to the `Routing Slip` and `Scatter-Gather` patterns.

Comment: From my Orchestration API I will be actually calling just 3-4 existing REST APIs (which are not exposed as Spring Integration endpoints). Also my use case is pretty simple if-else conditions. Having said that, do you think I should start designing my Orchestration API just Spring way and introduce Spring Integration (Routing Slip, Scatter-Gather patterns) if Orchestration Logic gets way too intrusive within Business logic?

Comment: 1. For `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` it doesn't matter if the target REST API is built on Spring Integration or not. 2. If you don't feel well with Spring Integration, just don't use it for this kind of task. 3. No reason to spend time to hit the wall by head, if you can achieve the goal with some other tool. I don't insist to use Spring Integration, if you don't like it. That's why this your question has been without an answer for a while: just because you are requesting about some opinion, but not the particular problem with the tool.

Comment: Thanks @Artem for the honest opinion, I am just making sure not killing an ant with a sledge hammer :)